# Display selectedAnnotation info

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkmapview

When I use this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)myMapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
        calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    NSLog(@"SelectedAnnotations is %@", myMapView.selectedAnnotations);
}
```

It Displays this in the log.

```
"<Annotation: 0x586cdb0>"
```

Now this is a weird question, but how do I get the info from this Annotation? I have lost my mind.

This is what is in the annotation.

```
myAnnotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];
myAnnotation.dealName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tempValue objectForKey:@"name"]];
myAnnotation.subName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Price: $%@",[tempValue objectForKey:@"price"]];
myAnnotation.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[tempValue objectForKey:@"dealLatitude"] doubleValue]];
myAnnotation.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[tempValue objectForKey:@"dealLongitude"] doubleValue]];
myAnnotation.dealId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[ [tempValue objectForKey:@"dId"] intValue ]];
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In calloutAccessoryControlTapped, the annotation tapped is available in the MKAnnotationView parameter:

```
Annotation *myAnnotation = (Annotation *)view.annotation;
```